# MySQL Error near END

Tags: mysql

I am not that great with MySQL (more used to SQL Server). For some reason this stored procedure is having a hard time wanting to add.
I've had this problem before, and normally I just get rid of 'BEGIN' and 'END' and it works but that doesn't seem like it's the right way to do it.

Here is the query:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetIngredientNames (IN ip VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    IF ip = '' THEN
        SET ip = 'No IP';
    END IF;
    SELECT I.Id, I.`Name`, I.`Description` FROM Ingredients I;
    INSERT INTO Log (Message, `IPAddress`) VALUE ('GetIngredientNames() called', @ip)
END;//
delimiter;
```

And version:

```
version 5.6.37
```

Can anyone help? Not sure why it always messes up on create procedure

Comment: remove the `;`: `END//`

Comment: Actually there are a lot of errors in your query (at least 3). Use a SQL tool like *MySQL Workbench* and go through them one by one.

Comment: I will try MySQL Workbench. Currently I am using Sequel Pro on my mac. I didn't think MySQL workbench was for mac but just found out it was. Hopefully this is better. Not a big fan of Sequel Pro

Comment: The last statement of your code reads: *"INSERT INTO Log (Message, `IPAddress`) VALUE ('GetIngredientNames() called', @ip) END"*. Can you spot the error now? The error message actually tells you where the error is: before "END".

Comment: ... no... VALUES instead of VALUE? I changed the @ip to ip and that still doesn't work

Comment: Finally got it. There was no semicolon at the end of the INSERT INTO... line